Use aliases in CASE in stored procedure
I have SQL Server stored procedure:
Select 
    A.Id, A.Title, A.BriefText, 
    I.ArticleView, U.DisplayName AS Author, 
    U.Avatar,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Articles_Like WHERE ArticleId = A.Id) AS Likes,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Articles_Comment WHERE ArticleId = A.Id) AS Comments,
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Articles_Like 
                     WHERE ArticleId = A.Id AND UserId = @UserId) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS IsLiked,
    CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Articles_Bookmark 
                     WHERE ArticleId = A.Id AND UserId = @UserId)
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
    END AS IsBookmarked
FROM 
    Articles A
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Articles_Info I ON I.ArticleId = A.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Users_Info U ON U.UserId = A.UserId
GROUP BY 
    A.Title, A.BriefText, A.Id, I.ArticleView, 
    U.DisplayName, U.Avatar, U.UserId 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @orderby = 1 THEN A.Id END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @orderby = 2 THEN I.ArticleView END DESC,
    END DESC
    CASE WHEN @orderby = 3 THEN Likes END DESC

On the last line
 CASE WHEN @orderby = 3 THEN Likes END DESC

I get an error:

Invalid column name

when I use CASE aliases is not working anymore, how can I fix this?
I can use:
CASE WHEN @orderby = 3 THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Articles_Like WHERE ArticleId = A.Id) END DESC

Like this:
Select A.Id, A.Title,  A.BriefText, I.ArticleView, U.DisplayName AS Author, U.Avatar,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Articles_Like WHERE ArticleId=A.Id) AS Likes,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Articles_Comment WHERE ArticleId=A.Id) AS Comments,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Articles_Like WHERE ArticleId=A.Id AND UserId=@UserId) 
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsLiked,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Articles_Bookmark WHERE ArticleId=A.Id AND UserId=@UserId)
         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsBookmarked
FROM Articles A
LEFT OUTER JOIN Articles_Info I ON I.ArticleId = A.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users_Info U ON U.UserId = A.UserId
GROUP BY A.Title, A.BriefText, A.Id, I.ArticleView, U.DisplayName, U.Avatar, U.UserId 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @orderby=1 THEN A.Id END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @orderby=2 THEN I.ArticleView END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @orderby=3 THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Articles_Like WHERE ArticleId=A.Id) END DESC

and it works but I used this code at the top of the stored precedure and it's not a right way to use a code twice.
I'm using SQL Server 2022

Column aliases cannot be used within that query. You could, if you want to avoid repetition, use a subquery or CTE and use the aliases from an inner query in an outer query.

There is an extra END DESC before that last case expression. This is easy to see if you take the minimal effort to format the code in a reasonable way.

@Alejandro well, aliases can be used in ORDER BY, but not in an expression context, ORDER BY Likes works fine for example

From the sql server docs

If the ORDER BY clause references a column alias from the select list, the column alias must be used on its own, and not as a part of some expression in ORDER BY clause, for example:
Copy
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName
FROM sys.objects
ORDER BY SchemaName; -- correct

SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName
FROM sys.objects
ORDER BY SchemaName + ''; -- wrong


You can see the same situation you are encountering with the following working/non-working example:
CREATE TABLE test (id int, f1 varchar(20));
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1, 'foo');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (2, 'bar');

/*runs fine*/
SELECT id, (SELECT count(*) FROM test) as total_count
FROM test
ORDER BY total_count

/*errors*/
SELECT id, (SELECT count(*) FROM test) as total_count
FROM test
ORDER BY CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN total_count END

dbfiddle here of this in action.

To avoid code duplication, consider tossing the query without the ORDER BY into a subquery and then ordering in the main query:
SELECT * 
FROM 
  (
    Select A.Id, A.Title,  A.BriefText, I.ArticleView, U.DisplayName AS Author, U.Avatar,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Articles_Like WHERE ArticleId=A.Id) AS Likes,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Articles_Comment WHERE ArticleId=A.Id) AS Comments,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Articles_Like WHERE ArticleId=A.Id AND UserId=@UserId) 
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsLiked,
        CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM Articles_Bookmark WHERE ArticleId=A.Id AND UserId=@UserId)
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsBookmarked
    FROM Articles A
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Articles_Info I ON I.ArticleId = A.Id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Users_Info U ON U.UserId = A.UserId
    GROUP BY A.Title, A.BriefText, A.Id, I.ArticleView, U.DisplayName, U.Avatar, U.UserId 
  ) dt
ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN @orderby=1 THEN Id END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @orderby=2 THEN ArticleView END DESC,
        CASE WHEN @orderby=3 THEN Likes END DESC



I used this code at the top of the stored precedure and it's not a right way to use a code twice

This is true for procedural languages, but unfortunately for SQL, to get the best results sometimes you do need to repeat complex expressions. Generally, the query engine is smart enough NOT to repeat the work, and will only execute the expression once, while still using it both places.
Similarly, because SQL is smart enough not to duplicate the work, you might reconsider how the IsLiked column is defined, so it re-uses the same expression and returns the correct value if the result is > 0.
